# Keygen.java X509Certificate generating

Tags: android

```
try (BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)){
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory(bufferedInputStream);
        }
```

Why certificateFactory can't use buffered input? How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
while (bufferedInputStream.available() >0){
Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(bufferedInputStream);
globalPublicCert = certificate;
}